# Query on Elasticsearch with wildcard path field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to save some similar JSONs in one index in elasticsearch
These are 2 samples:
1.

```
{
    "data": {
        "other-fields":"value",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

2. 

```
{
    "some-fields": "some-values",
    "data": {
        "other-fields": "other-value",
        "Location": {
            "country": "USA"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to know how can I query on Elasticsearch 8.6 to get all documents with {"country":"USA"} through a dynamic query. Consider that there are other samples which "country" path is different from these samples and I don't want to specify "country" path.

In this query I should write country path:

```
POST /index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",         
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "data.location.country": "USA" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I found how to query with dynamic path, I should implement it with spring data

Comment: it is generally NOT a good idea to store documents having different schema/mapping in the same index. You should either transform each document into a common schema or store them in different indexes.

Comment: In addition to what Val said, Spring Data Elasticsearch could map something like this only to ` Map<String, Object>`, basically  simple JSON representation and not to any entity classes.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Yes, my field type is Map<String, Object>

Comment: that makes me wonder why you use Spring Data Elasticsearch at all and not just use the plain Elasticsearch client